# Can every X.509 v3 certificate be used as authenticode certificate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssl, code-signing, x509, authenticode

I have a X.509 v3 issued by a CA within my company. I am using ClickOnce deployment in Viusal Studio and I want to use code signing. When I click on "Choose from store" the certificate is not shown in the list. That´s why I think it cannot be used as a authenticode certificate.

My question is: Can every X.509 v3 certificate be used as a authenticode certificate for code signing (e.g. in Visual Studio)? And if not: How do I determine whether the certificate is a valid authenticode certificate?

Thanks for reading my question.

Regards
Philipp

Comment: AFAIR the certificate must contain the value "Code signing(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)" in the extended usage field. Just open a certificate used by Microsoft, Adobe, ... for signing the EXE-Installer of an application and you will see this value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me where I can see the EKU of a certificate. In the internet options in control panel I can only see the field "Key Usage". And I have another certificate which is shown in Visual Studio for code signing, but I can not see any EKU there, too.

Comment: I don't believe there is such as thing as X.509 V2. I'm pretty sure it went from V1 to V3. According to [Object IDs associated with Microsoft cryptography](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/287547), Microsoft's Authenticode OID is `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2`.

Comment: You are right, it´s v3. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

X.509 certificates used with Authenticode typically would have the Extended Key Usage (EKU) "Code Signing" indicating that the certificate can only be used for code signing purposes.